# sunspot - indexing has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot

I have the following 'submission' model.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "SUBMISSION"
  self.primary_key = "SUB_ID"

  has_one  :publication,             :foreign_key => "PUB_SUBMISSION_FK", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one  :refpublication,          :through => :publication

  belongs_to :submitter, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "SUB_SUBMITTER_FK"


  #***************************************************************************************
  #Solr searchable attributes
  #***************************************************************************************

searchable do

  text :publication_PUB_REF_ID do
    publication.PUB_REF_ID
  end

  text :submitter_PER_NAME do
    submitter.PER_NAME
  end

  text :SUB_OID, :boost => 5
  text :SUB_ASSAY_TYPE

end

end #end of submission class
```

When I run rake sunspot:reindex, I get

rake aborted!
undefined method `PUB_REF_ID' for nil:NilClass.

I can't see what is wrong with the code above.  `PUB_REF_ID'  is a field in the 'publications' table
Is there something wrong with the way I am indexing 'has_one' association?

Your help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :)

Not all submissions had rows in my 'publications' table.

Here's the solution I used:

Instead of:

```
 text :publication_PUB_REF_ID do
    publication.PUB_REF_ID
  end
```

I use:

```
 text :publication_PUB_REF_ID do
      publication.nil?? '' : (publication.PUB_REF_ID.nil?? '' : publication.PUB_REF_ID)
    end
```

Hope this could be of help to someone else :)